# How to bring all desired UI Interface objects and views to the front?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I have a background image for the view controller and two labels. The two labels are not showing up because they are behind the imageview. When I go to editor->arrange the send to front option is not available for the labels. And when I check on the layout debugger I can see the labels are behind the imageview. Is there another way to bring to the labels in front?

Comment: Can you just send the background image to the back instead of trying to send everything else to the front?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using IB, you can move things to the front/back of one another by rearranging them in the left panel. The first item in the list will lie behind every other item. So in this case your list of subviews should go:
1. Image
2. Label
3. Label

This will result in the labels lying one top of the image.